# Find strings that begins with a '#' and create link

Tags: python, regex, django, string, hashtag

I want to check whether a string (a tweet) begins with a '#' (i.e. is a hashtag) or not, and if so create a link.

Below is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work (error on the last line).
How can I fix this and will the code work for the purpose?

```
tag_regex = re.compile(r"""
       [\b#\w\w+]        # hashtag found!""", re.VERBOSE)

message = raw_message

for tag in tag_regex.findall(raw_message):
    message = message.replace(url, '<a href="http://statigr.am/tag/' + message[1:] + '/">' + message + '</a>')
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: @Haidro: "local variable 'url' referenced before assignment"

Comment: There must be more in your code then that you aren't showing us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> msg = '#my_tag the rest of my tweet'
>>> re.sub('^#(\w+) (.*)', r'<a href="http://statigr.am/tag/\1">\2</a>', msg)
'<a href="http://statigr.am/tag/my_tag">the rest of my tweet</a>'
>>>
```